# Perl: preserving whitespace in empty CDATA block in xml file

Tags: xml, perl, xml-parsing

so as my title suggests: i have an XML file with the following relevant content

```
<element>
    <id>ID</id>
    <content>
        <![CDATA[ 



        ]]>
    </content>
</element>
```

I am using XML::Simple to parse this:

```
$localElement = XMLin( $localElementXML, NoAttr=>1, SuppressEmpty=>'' )
```

which results in this perl hash:

```
{
  'content' => '',
  'id' => 'ID'
};
```

If I insert anything other than whitespace in the middle of that empty CDATA block, all the whitespace is preserved:

```
{
  'content' => '


    --


',
  'id' => 'ID'
};
```

What I need to achieve is for the whitespace to be preserved (in basically a long, empty string) even if there are no other characters in the middle of it. Yes, I am using "SuppressEmpty", but I'm thinking that element isn't empty, it's a CDATA-block full of spaces, linebreaks, etc. Am I missing something? How can I get this to work? I haven't found any obvious options for XML::Simple to change this behaviour.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Put simply, [XML::Simple](http://metacpan.org/module/XML::Simple) is dreadful. Don't use it. Its own documnetation says *The use of this module in new code is discouraged. Other modules are available which provide more straightforward and consistent interfaces.*

Answer (score 3):

Here is your problem:

> I am using `XML::Simple` to parse this:

Don't. [`XML::Simple`](http://search.cpan.org/~grantm/XML-Simple-2.20/lib/XML/Simple.pm) even says 'don't use this module'.

> The use of this module in new code is discouraged. Other modules are available which provide more straightforward and consistent interfaces.

The reason is quite simple - only very trivial (or indeed - simple) pieces of XML can be directly represented via arrays and hashes.

How about [`XML::Twig`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Twig/Twig.pm):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new( 'pretty_print' => 'indented_a' )->parse( \*DATA );

$twig->print;

my $content = $twig->root->first_child('content')->text;
print "Content is :\"", $content, "\"\n";

__DATA__
<element>
    <id>ID</id>
    <content>
        <![CDATA[ 



        ]]>
    </content>
</element>
```

Which prints:

```
<element>
  <id>ID</id>
  <content><![CDATA[ 



        ]]></content>
</element>
Content is :" 



        "
```

Of course, from there, the next question is - what do you want to *do* with that content.